# How to make realtime location from firebase?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: My database]

and my code

```
var pointRef = myDataRef.child("locations");

function requestMarkerLocations(pointRef) {

snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
            var id = childSnapshot.key();

pointRef.child(id).once("value", function (snapshot) {

    var newPosition = id.val();
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(newPosition.lat,
        newPosition.lng);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map: map
    });        
});
});
}
```

I need to show all markers and move them after I changed lat and Ing in the firebase.

Comment: You should use API Reference | GeoFire for JavaScript https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `once()` function which reads data only once. You should use the `on()` instead since it gets called everytime data is updated in the node where the listener has been attached to:

```
pointRef.child(id).on("value", function (snapshot) {

    var newPosition = id.val();
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(newPosition.lat,
        newPosition.lng);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map: map
    });        
});
```